# i have many image buttons in gridview one column.ie.how to find control of each image button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i have one gridview with one column with many imagebuttons.there are nearly 20 imagebuttons in one column and first row of  gridview.how to find control of each imagebutton.in the gridview i have a button, inside this button click event i need  to find control of image button.I am not able to find it.

```
     protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton)GridView2.FindControl("ImageButton4");
        bool clicked = ViewState[imgButton.ID] == null ? true : false;
        if (clicked.Equals(ViewState[imgButton.ID] = true))
        {
             a = 1;
        }
        ImageButton imgButton1 = (ImageButton)FindControl("ImageButton6");
        bool clicked1 = ViewState[imgButton1.ID] == null ? true : false;
        if (clicked1.Equals(ViewState[imgButton1.ID] = true))
        {
            a = 2;
        }


        Session["a"] = a;

        Response.Redirect("customerinfo.aspx");

    }
```